# How to test with any integer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

Is there something I can replace the '1' with as a wildcard (any number greater than 0) so that for anything passed in this always returns the same thing etc?

```
[TestMethod]
public void GameManagersEventsIndexReturnedWhenUserHasNoLocations()
{
    // Arrange
    List<CustomerLocation> locations = new List<CustomerLocation>();
    locations.Add(new CustomerLocation() { Active = true, Name = "Ted" });

    customerLocationDataProvider.Setup(x => x.GetAllForUserId(1)).Returns(locations);
    customerLocationDataProvider.Setup(x => x.GetAllForUserId(1).Count).Returns(0);
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using MOQ, you can do

```
x => x.GetAllForUserId(It.Is<int>(i => i > 0)) // condition that int value is > 0 or you can have any other conditions
```

or

```
x => x.GetAllForUserId(It.IsAny<int>()) //if you don't care about the value
```